# How do I Iterate through different tag names (h3) and compare their text using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium

My goal is to find a product listing by its name then click on it. Currently I want to iterate through all the text with the tag name h3 using a for loop and end the loop when the text is equal to the product I want. Now obviously, my code currently finds the very first listing then iterates through the characters in the string. What I want it to do is iterate through the different elements and pull out their text. I would appreciate any suggestions and will be quick to answer any questions. Thank you!

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/Users/devinhadley/Desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.set_window_size(200, 200)
driver.get("https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/")

elements = []
elements = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text


for element in elements:
    print(element)
    if element = "PERTEX PACKET JACKET GREY"
        print("Done")
```

Comment: Hi! Please check my answer and let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: Sorry about that was testing some things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/Users/devinhadley/Desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.set_window_size(200, 200)
driver.get("https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/")

elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")

for element in elements:
    if element.text == "PERTEX PACKET JACKET GREY":
          print(element)
```

---

**Update:** I opened the webpage and I realized that `find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")` won't work. The following will do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "/Users/devinhadley/Desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.set_window_size(200, 200)
driver.get("https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/")

elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-alpha]')))

for element in elements:
    
    if element.get_attribute('data-alpha') == "PERTEX PACKET JACKET GREY":
    
          print(element.get_attribute('data-alpha'))
          element.click()
```

If you want to click on a particular element, you can either do `element.click()` inside the for loop or `elements[0].click()`, for example, if you want to click the first element.

Comment: Awesome perfect solution for iterating through. For some reason it is still tossing an error when trying to place element.click() within the if statement.

Comment: Wow man you are very kind, I just got into python automation today and it is wonderful to see such descriptive help!

Comment: Glad I helped! good luck with the python automation :)

Comment: Okay sorry, when the program is running it does not actually open the listing.

Comment: Close it and try again.

Comment: I restarted both the editor and all open chrome windows. Still the same issue. If you would like I can record and upload a video of what it looks like.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ? The code works for me fine.

Comment: It's not throwing an error, rather it's not clicking on the listing. So the program just stops running once it finds the element rather than clicking on and opening the listing.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. I used the location of the element rather than the element itself, applied an offset, then clicked the location.